# Android: Show Dialogs Based on Logcat Response

Tags: android, web-services, response, android-logcat

I am working on web services. I want to show dialog box according to logcat response which come as a single string. How could i parse that single reponse and show the dialog to user. My string response is of three types which are 1, -1, 0. I need to show two dialogs. one for string type = 1 and another for string type = 0 and -1. This is my code. any idea?

```
    package com.soap;

          import java.util.regex.Matcher;
          import java.util.regex.Pattern;

          import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
          import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
          import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
          import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
          import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
          import android.app.Activity;
          import android.app.AlertDialog;
          import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
          import android.app.Dialog;
          import android.app.ProgressDialog;
          import android.content.DialogInterface;
          import android.content.Intent;
          import android.os.Bundle;
          import android.util.Log;
          import android.view.View;
          import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
          import android.widget.Button;
          import android.widget.EditText;

          public class Register extends Activity {
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */

 // static Spinner operator = null;
 private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "My Link";
 private static final String METHOD_NAME = "My Link";
 private static final String NAMESPACE = "My Link";
 private static final String URL = "My Link";
 private static final String TAG = "HELLO";


 String resultsRequestSOAP = null;
 //resultsRequestSOAP 1;

 Thread t;
 ProgressDialog dialog;
 //Builder builder;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.forgotpasswordpage);
  Button signin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fpwdsubmit);

  signin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
    showDialog(0);
    t = new Thread() {
     public void run() {
      register();
     }
    };
    t.start();
   }
  });
 }

 @Override
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
  switch (id) {
  case 0: {
   dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
   dialog.setMessage("Please wait while connecting...");

   dialog.setCancelable(true);
   return dialog;
  }
  }
  return null;
 }

 public void register() {
  Log.v(TAG, "Trying to Login");
  EditText etxt_user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fpedtext);
  String email_id = etxt_user.getText().toString();
  SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
  request.addProperty("Email", email_id);
   Pattern EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN =Pattern.compile(
              "[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}" +
              "\\@" +
              "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}" +
              "(" +
              "\\." +
              "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25}" +
              ")+");
      Matcher matcher = EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN.matcher(email_id);
      if(matcher.matches()){
       Log.v(TAG, "Your email id is valid ="+email_id);

      }
      else{

       Log.v(TAG, "enter valid email id" );
      }

 SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
  soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
  soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
  HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
  try {
         aht.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"); 
   aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
        SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
   Log.v("TAG1", String.valueOf(resultsRequestSOAP));
   dialog.dismiss();

   //String resultData;
  // resultData = request.getProperty(0).toString();
  } 
catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can't see any code for showing the dialogs in your post. By the way, why using strings? Why don't you just send an int value?

Comment: @Egor I cant edit the ques some locked i think.... ya my ques is how parse and show dialog to the user....

Comment: So, why are you using Strings instead of integers? And I really don't get the problem, what's the problem in showing a dialog when you have a value?

Comment: @Egor they giving the response as string only... how can i parse the result and show the dialog....

Comment: then you should use Integer.parseInt(String value) to get the int result